# Localized Abbreviation from an NSTimeZone

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, datetime

I'm having trouble getting a localized timezone (e.g., EST/EDT, PST/PDT, etc.) from an `NSTimeZone`, when it has been initialized from a GMT offset.  If I initialize from an abbreviation, it works fine.

For example, if I initialize the `NSTimeZone` with an abbreviation, I get the expected result:

```
let zoneNameStyle = NSTimeZoneNameStyle.ShortStandard
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

var tz = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
tz.localizedName(zoneNameStyle, locale: locale)  //evaluates to "EST"
```

But, if I initialize the `NSTimeZone` with an offset from GMT, I unexpectedly get:

```
tz = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: (-5 * 60 * 60))
tz.localizedName(zoneNameStyle, locale: locale)  //evaluates to "GMT-5"
```

Is there a way to make an `NSTimeZone` initialized from an offset to return a localized time zone name, instead of the "GMT-5"-style result?